# iFrameResizer plugin not resizing iframe

Tags: iframe-resizer

I have implemented the iFrameResizer plugin [here](http://staging.chapmancaravans.com.au/finance/apply-for-finance.php) with the following settings:

```
$('#iframeResizer').iFrameResize({
                    log                     : true,
                    scrolling               : true,
                    enablePublicMethods     : true,            // Enable methods within iFrame hosted page
                    heightCalculationMethod : 'lowestElement'
                    });
```

and the iframeSizer.contentWindow.min.js has been added to the iframe content window - I can see that the scroll bars are working which tells me the iFrame Resizer plugin has been implemented correctly - but the height is not resizing correctly??

Here are the console results [image]

I thought perhaps maybe the problem could be from the iFrame content being hosted on a secure server????

If anybody is able to offer some advice or suggestions I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the checkOrigin option.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/blob/master/docs/parent_page/options.md#checkorigin

Comment: Hi David Thanks for your reply... I have 2 questions - 1. Could you give me an example of how to write the checkOrigin array? (I am not 100% sure how to go about this.) 2. If I set the checkOrigin option will this effect other iFrames that are using this plugin within the site? Or should I keep them seperate by creating different ID's? Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Hi David, I've confirmed the content page within the iFrame navigates within the same domain, port and protocol... so I have set the checkOrigin to true but it is still not resizing... any other suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The second js file needs including in every page in your iframe

Comment: Hi David, I've confirmed with the developers from the website running the content page within the iFrame and they say that the js plugin is included within each page...

Comment: If you set checkOrigin to false does the issue go away?

Comment: No - the iframe is still not resizing even with checkOrigin set to false... fyi, as a test I set the scrollbar to true and that part is working...

Comment: Just looked at your site, the `iFrameResizer.contentWindow.js` is not being loaded into the iframe.

Comment: Hi David, thanks so much for your assistance - you were correct. The iFrameResizer.contentWindow.js file was only included in the mobile only version. The problem has now been rectified and it is working perfectly. :-)